# CSS based Slider Issue (Firefox, Chrome & IE)

Tags: html, css, slider

I have downloaded a new slider which is CSS and HTML based, no javascript.  I am having a few issues across browsers and was hoping that someone may have knowledge on how to fix it.

Firefox:  Slider navigation (previous, next, thumbs) are not working and hyperlinks not working.  I thought I could just use z-index to remedy, but no luck.

Chrome: Same as Firefox, Slider navigation (previous, next, thumbs) are not working and hyperlinks not working.  I thought I could just use z-index to remedy, but no luck.

IE:  Seems like the slider may work at first, but then appears to get "stuck" and "twitches"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My slider can be found here:  http://online.saintleo.edu

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your website.  Your `<div id="page">` is overlaying on top of the slider.

the styling:

```
#page{
     padding-top:432px;
}
```

seems to be what is doing it.

replace it with `margin-top` or `position:relative; top: 432px;` and you should be able to use your slider again.

As for the IE bug, I believe its just a matter of some css selectors or properties not being supported yet.

Comment: Steve, I can't thank you enough.  That did the trick.  Thank you so much for being so kind.